# How to create a custom ID for an item in a discord-py-slash-command dropdown?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-interactions

I am using a library called [discord-py-slash-command](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) to implement slash commands and dropdown menus into my discord bot, coded in discord.py.

##### The Problem:

My problem is that I am unable to assign custom IDs to different items, and therefore I cannot identify the selected item. Using a separate bot event will not work for me.

##### My Code:

I have successfully created a basic dropdown menu with the following code:

```py
select = create_select(
        options=[
            create_select_option("Option 1", value="Option 1", emoji="1️⃣"),
            create_select_option("Option 2", value="Option 2", emoji="2️⃣"),
            create_select_option("Option 3", value="Option 3", emoji="3️⃣"),
        ],
        placeholder="Choose an option or two", 
        min_values=1,
        max_values=2, 
        )
    await user.send("Select options here", components=[create_actionrow(select)])
```

I then use the following code to wait for selected items and then send the results:

```py
select_ctx: ComponentContext = await wait_for_component(client, components=create_actionrow(select))
await select_ctx.edit_origin(content=f"You chose an option!")
```

I would like to be able to assign a custom ID to each select option in the top code block because the random IDs generated for you are very long and unmemorable, such as:

`7816e661-7751-4e1b-8ab0-24b00a0537cc`

##### What I have tried:

I've tried adding both `custom_id` and `id` parameters to each select option in `select`. When I do so, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: create_select_option() got an unexpected keyword argument 'custom_id'
```

Is assigning custom IDs only available for buttons or am I assigning the ID in the wrong place? I'd appreciate any answers or feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out the docs?

Comment: Yes, I've read through it multiple times, but the only explanations I've found are here: https://discord-py-slash-commands.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components.html#how-do-i-know-which-button-was-pressed

Comment: Hmm, I went through them. There are ```custom_ids``` for slash commands and buttons but not for dropdowns. Try asking in their [discord server](https://discord.gg/pb8D7DSR)

Comment: Asking a question now, thanks. My main goal is to find a way to identify which item was chosen. Do you think there is an alternate way hidden in the docs?

Comment: Wait, I just found out, I have used a custom id for my dropdown. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `custom_id` for dropdowns. You place it exactly after the `min` and `max` values.

```py
Select = create_select(options = [
    create_select_option("Option 1", value="Option 1", emoji="1️⃣"),
    create_select_option("Option 1", value="Option 1", emoji="1️⃣"),
    create_select_option("Option 1", value="Option 1", emoji="1️⃣"),
        ],
        placeholder="Choose a help category",
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
        custom_id="helpuwu",    
    )
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use this to find out which item was selected?

Comment: You use ```value``` for that. The ```value``` of the ```select_option```.  Also if the answer helped, accept the answer so that people know that it has been answered!